# vue-owl-carousel2 не работает responsive

Tags: vue.js, owl-carousel

Имеется код:

```
 <template>
  <slider class='slider' 
   :items='8'
   :responsive='{0:{items:1}, 600:{items:3}}'
   >
  <div class='slider__image' v-for='(image, index) in images' :key='index'>
    <a :href='`${image.link}`'>  
      <div class='slider__item' :style='{backgroundImage: `url(${image.logo.url})`}'> </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Не срабатывает :responsive, не могу разобраться почему :/

Comment: может у вас всетаки 1 версия, проверьте ваш package.json

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович   "dependencies": {
    "vue-owl-carousel2": "^2.0.7"

Comment: @Alex, стоит проверить фактически скачанную версию зависимости, т.к. указание версии в `package.json` само по себе не гарантирует того что подходящая версия находится в `node_modules`. Выполни `$ npm list vue-owl-carousel2` в директории проекта. А если установлена подходящая версия - стоит проверить значение пропса компонента через Vue devtools (если и пропс в порядке, то открывать issue в репо библиотеки).

Comment: @yar85 Разобрался. Сова почему-то не понимает циклы. Убрал его, поставил обычные картинки - все настройки срабатывают. Но теперь непонятно, что делать с циклом :/